PowerPoint VBA code for pulling out a slides comments status's
I am looking for help getting the status of comments (not notes) in PowerPoint VBA.
I have the code for looping through an active presentation, through the slides and pulling some of the comment info such as author and text.
But I can't see how to get to the status.  By status I mean if a comment is 'Resolved' or 'Open'.
Appreciate any help on this, thanks.
PowerPoint Comment

PowerPoint Comment Resolved


How are you marking a comment's status as resolved or open? I'm not seeing a "status" marking during or after creation of a comment.

If you click on the 3 dots next to the 'like thumb' there is an option to 'Resolve Thread'.
This sets the comment to 'Resolved'

Not sure if it's a version issue, but I don't see that option available in my PowerPoint. Looking in the Microsoft documentation, I see the Done flag available to the Comment object in Word, but it's not available in PowerPoint.

I am using Office365 so its the latest version of PowerPoint.  I have added a couple of screenshots of a comment before and after its 'Resolved'.
In Word I use the .Done flag but as you say its not available in PowerPoint so I am trying to work out how to capture the Comment status

@PeterT, it's not just the version, it also depends on whether Modern comments have been enabled. Modern comments in PP can be "resolved", the same way as in Word. However, I don't think the VBA object model has caught up with it yet. So the likely answer is "you can't"

Hi, this problem resembles this question. Refer to my answer for a workaround for it, since this does not have an implementation on VBA, but I think the "resolved" property is there
